# Microsoft Clarity: How to filter customers who started purchase but didn't finish checkout?

Tags: ms-clarity

I have experience with other heatmap services, and you can always set a filter that includes 1 page and doesn't include another page.
So you can see which users started a process but didn't finish it.
Is it even possible with MS Clarity?

I've been stragling with setting this up. Not sure if that is possible.

Cheers
D

Comment: This site is for questions about programming